# jQuery moving DIVS down with collapsable content

Tags: jquery, css, html

In a bit of a mess with the CSS with this little app i'm working on. 
https://modstudio.eu/facebook/hq/test.php

I cannot seem to figure out how to move the content down when the click me button is pressed, any ideas? i'm guessing its a CSS problem, something to do with the position:?

Comment: What do you mean with "move the content down" ? You mean move it to the end of the list?

Comment: it was more to move the content and provide space for the DIV when clicked. Its working now :) you can take a look if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `slide_wrapper` div has a set height. Therefore the content of that div will never expand past the height specified. If you were to change the `height: 100px` css rule to `min-height: 100px`, then you get the desired effect.